# If two groups are isomorphic, then one is finitely generated iff the other is.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is this statement true?  I'm guessing it's obvious, but I don't see why.

Comment: If $\varphi : G \to G'$ is an isomorphism, then go to the definition of "finitely generated" and insert a bunch of $\varphi$s and $\varphi^{-1}$s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image under an isomorphism of a set of generators of one group is a set of generators of the other.

Comment: And the inverse of an isomorphism is again an isomorphism.